# How to get the size of a web page (its content)?

Tags: page-size

How can you find what a particular web page is in size (i.e. MBs)? Before you could right click on a page and choose 'Show Page Info' and there it was. What about now?

EDIT: Ideally a way to do it in Safari or Chrome.

Comment: What is your ultimate goal once you get a page size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible using Firefox and I believe Chrome as well (someone please confirm this).

In Firefox go to Developer Tools > Network. Here there is a performance analysis tool that checks the size of the page with no caching and also with a primed cache.

Comment: It works in Chrome, you just have to do cache reload of the page (if you already visited that page).